S3 event integration and Auto copy Job
Inside S3 event integration, have created one AUTO COPY JOB which detects new file upload in S3 bucket and loads data into Amazon Redshift.
Its observed that after 1 hour this job doesn't do anything (no error).
Once Drop and Re-Created that job it again works for 1 hour and goes into same situation where it doesn't do anything (no error).
role used in creating COPY JOB having maximum session duration 2 hours.
so after 2 hours if this happens then its understandable, any help in this matter would be appreciated.
Below is Trusted Relationships --> Trusted entities for specific role which is used in creating COPY job
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

